# Cannot get form data to post to SQL (using MySQL 5.5.25)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a project and I'm having a bit of trouble getting my form data to post to my SQL database.  At first the auto inc ID values were working any time I'd submit the form, but no other data would post... now nothing at all happens...  I'm very rusty with php... anyways here is what I have so far.

insert.php

```
<?php
include ("connect.php");
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'tc_db'.'teamchiefs' ('lastname',  'firstname','unit','datecert','initial')
VALUES ('$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[unit]','$_POST[datecert]')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error:' . mysqli_error(@con));
}
echo "Record Added";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And my form.html file... clipped down to save space.

```
<body>
<ul>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
"sprytextfield1">
<label>Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
</label>
<label>First Name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
  </label>
<label>Middle Initial
  <input name="initial" type="text" id="initial" size="5" maxlength="1" />
</label>

...etc

//spry widget javascript stuff here

</form>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

My sql tables are

```
ID - BIGINT(20) - A_I
lastname - VARCHAR(60)
firstname - VARCHAR(60)
unit - VARCHAR(6)
datecert - YEAR(4)
initial - VARCHAR(1)
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: **You are wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: It is hosted locally right now, I have not secured it.  Just trying to get it to work first.

Comment: "Security, like correctness, is not an add-on feature." -- Andrew S. Tanenbaum

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO 'tc_db'.'teamchiefs'
```

Use backticks for table and column names

```
INSERT INTO `tc_db`.`teamchiefs`
```

Comment: Awwwwhh yusss... I feel so dumb for not noticing... must be my flu daze... works now, thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

You have declared that you're inserting into five columns `('lastname',  'firstname','unit','datecert','initial')` but you're only providing four values `('$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[unit]','$_POST[datecert]')`. Looks like you're missing a value for `initial`. That's will cause your query to fail.

Comment: Ok, I added that in, still not posting though...

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `teamchiefs` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
No results :(